# How to count streak using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

this is my input table:

```
    DAY_ID  ARTICLE QTY
01.01.2014  000032  1
02.01.2014  000032  0
03.01.2014  000032  0
04.01.2014  000032  1
05.01.2014  000032  0
06.01.2014  000032  0
07.01.2014  000032  0
08.01.2014  000032  1
09.01.2014  000032  1
10.01.2014  000032  0
11.01.2014  000032  0
12.01.2014  000032  1
13.01.2014  000032  0
```

Here is the additional column "streak" which I want to get:

```
DAY_ID  ARTICLE QTY streak
01.01.2014  000032  1   
02.01.2014  000032  0   1
03.01.2014  000032  0   2
04.01.2014  000032  1   
05.01.2014  000032  0   1
06.01.2014  000032  0   2
07.01.2014  000032  0   3
08.01.2014  000032  1   
09.01.2014  000032  1   
10.01.2014  000032  0   1
11.01.2014  000032  0   2
12.01.2014  000032  1   
13.01.2014  000032  0   1
```

How can I achieve this using oracle?

Comment: "streak" appears to be a column not a row. What exactly are you trying to count? What's the expected output from your sample data?

Comment: hi! change question a bit for more inderstanding

Comment: Understood. Any solution to this will require a way of sorting the records into the correct order. Is there a timestamp, or a numeric primary key that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: yep there is date colomn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you succeed in grouping your values by "1st day ID" (the nearest day ID from previous days where quantity is 1), then you can achieve that:

```
select y.*, case when rnk = 1 then null else rnk - 1 end streak
from
(
  select x.*,
         row_number() over (partition by article, day_id_first order by day_id) rnk
  from
  (
    select t.*,
           (select max(t2.day_id) from my_table t2 where t2.day_id <= t.day_id and t2.qty = 1) day_id_first
    from my_table t
  ) x
) y
;
```

I kept all intermediate results to detail my computation, here is what you get:

```
DAY_ID        ARTICLE   QTY  DAY_ID_FIRST  RNK  STREAK
01.01.2014    000032    1    01.01.2014    1    
02.01.2014    000032    0    01.01.2014    2    1
03.01.2014    000032    0    01.01.2014    3    2
04.01.2014    000032    1    04.01.2014    1    
05.01.2014    000032    0    04.01.2014    2    1
06.01.2014    000032    0    04.01.2014    3    2
07.01.2014    000032    0    04.01.2014    4    3
08.01.2014    000032    1    08.01.2014    1    
09.01.2014    000032    1    09.01.2014    1    
10.01.2014    000032    0    09.01.2014    2    1
11.01.2014    000032    0    09.01.2014    3    2
12.01.2014    000032    1    12.01.2014    1    
13.01.2014    000032    0    12.01.2014    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which works with the data you've provided. For each row I'm working out the most recent date where QTY=1  (same as Emmanuel), but then I'm simply subtracting the dates.

Emmanuel's use of analytics means a more flexible solution. If you know there's only ever going to be one record per day, mine should work, although it would need amending if there can be more than one unique value of ARTICLE.

```
with streak_table as 
(select 
   day_id
  ,article
  ,qty
  ,(select max(yt2.day_id) 
    from your_table yt2 
    where yt2.day_id <= yt1.day_id and yt2.qty=1) reset
from your_table yt1)
select day_id
      ,article
      ,qty
      ,decode(day_id - reset, 0, null, day_id - reset) streak
from streak_table
order by day_id
```